# XML parser, recover=True?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse some XML, however I get an error message.
After looking around a little I suspect it is due to some kind of special character in the source text and a (recover=True) should be placed in my parser line.
However I do not know the exact location for this.
Could someone have a look?

```
for name in newlist:
tree = ET.parse(loc + name)     

root = tree.getroot()           

for post in root.findall('post'):   

    text = post.text                

    text = text.strip()                     

    posts.append(text)
```

The error I get is:

```
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 103, column 225
```

Comment: You mix tabs and spaces in your code; please fix the question so that the code is properly indented. Mixing tabs and spaces should be avoided in source code, too.

Answer (score 0):

im not familar with python but I've had issues like this using c#.  It might be because the xml isnt formatted properly.  Normally the first line of the xml file will contain something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

the version and encoding is important as it tells the parser what characters are allowed.  UTF-8 is the default but sometimes the xml file will contain non ascii characters causing this to go crazy.  Changing the encoding to UTF-16 sometimes fixes this.

Good luck

Comment: The problem is that I'm dealing with 20.000 xml files, manually fixing ever xml files would take days.

Comment: not sure what to tell you.  I would try to fix one of them and see if it works.  If it does then at least you know the answer and where to go with it.  In my case I was able to override the formatting in the code because the xml files where not ones I generated.  They came from a third party.

Comment: like i said, Im not a python programmer so I cant help you with that part of it.  Just attempting to share my experience with a similar issue in c#

Comment: Well thanks a million for the help, but also the XML files have no such header...